# how do I use python in monodevelop>

Tags: python, .net, mono, python.net

I have a solution mostly in C#, but with a python project. It runs using mono, but monodevelop 5.10 says it can't load a project with a .pyproj file. I assume I need to add python support, but don't see python.net in language bindings.  Also, I need python.net and not iron python.  I'm using linux mint 18, mono 5.4.0.201.  Thanks.

Comment: From [the manual](https://pythonnet.github.io/): "Running on Linux/Mono: Unit testing shows that PythonNet will run under Mono, though the Mono runtime is less supported so there still may be problems."

Comment: For latest Mono you need to install from master branch: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Installation